# (a)Smack: Invalid presence type probe

Tags: xmpp, smack

I am using aSmack 4.0.6 to connect XMPP server. In aSmack library, presence with type "probe" is not currently available and I got "invalid presence type probe" exception. How can I process presence with type "probe"?

Also, where should I find open source code (java files) of "aSmack 4.0.6" library?

Answer (score 1):

Presences with type 'probe' are supported with Smack 4.1 or higher. Smack 4.0 does not support them and throws the exception, but you can

```
XMPPTCPConnection.setParsingExceptionCallback(new ExceptionLoggingCallback())
```

to avoid disconnects because of presence probes.

Comment: I have downloaded aSmack's library source code from http://asmack.freakempire.de/4.0.7/ and updated "Presence.java" file by adding "probe" under "Type" enum and its working correctly now.